# Permission denied when compiling multiple protobuf files

Tags: javascript, grpc, protoc

Trying to compile multiple protobuf files within a single directory in Window using grpc-tools but it is giving the error Permission denied.

```
// this works 
grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:../static_codegen/ --grpc_out=../static_codegen helloworld.proto

// this doesn't
grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:../static_codegen/ --grpc_out=../static_codegen .

// this doesn't as well
grpc_tools_node_protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:../static_codegen/ --grpc_out=../static_codegen *
```

how to compile multiple files within a single directory